# How Do I Pass State (Value) when Calling Component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React APP which displays images perfectly fine from the Flickr API based on a 'dogs' query which is built into the code--this is container which accomplishes this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import apiKey from './config.js';
import Navigation from './Navigation.js';
import Photos from './Photos.js';
import SearchBar from './SearchBar.js';

class Container extends Component {

  constructor (){
    super();
    this.state = {
        imgs:[],
        query: '',
        loading: true
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.performSearch();

}

  performSearch = (query = 'dogs') => {
    axios.get(`https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=${apiKey}&tags=${query}&per_page=24&format=json&nojsoncallback=1`)
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({ 
        imgs: response.data.photos.photo,
        loading: false
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Error happened during fetching!', err);
    });
  }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
            <SearchBar onSearch={this.performSearch}/>
             <Navigation />
              {
                (this.state.loading)
                ? <p>Loading....</p>
                : <Photos data={this.state.imgs}/>
              }
            </div>
            );
    }
}
export default Container;
```

I have a nav bar with three different links--and I would like to call the Container component for each-- passing a specific value for the query in the API.

So for example, if my links are bears, cats, and mice, I would like the respective link to generate the correct api based on the query term.

I am just uncertain as to how I pass the query term utilizing the Container component.  Go easy, as I'm a bit new to react, but I was trying something like

```
<Container query="bears" />
```

or

```
<Container performSearch("bears") />
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to pass the appropriate value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to pass the query in as a prop. I would begin by updating the constructor to receive `props`, pass them to `super()`, and use them to set the value of the state's `query` property:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        imgs: [],
        query: this.props.query,
        loading: true
    }
}
```

Next, update the `performSearch()` method to use the state's `query` property instead of the hard-coded `'dogs'` value:

```
performSearch = (query = this.state.query) => {
```

Now you can pass the appropriate `query` property to the `Container` like you were thinking:

```
<Container query="bears" />
<Container query="cats" />
<Container query="mice" />
```

Comment: You're a genius.  Exactly what I needed to do.  Thank you.